# Pasaje por referencia

Tags: c

En este ejercicio cuando quiero imprimir el resultado osea 'ganador' no aparece nada ¿dónde estaría el error?

En este código tengo que usar en la función con pasaje por referencia que aún me es difícil entender bien, de paso alguna sugerencia para el tema.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char duelo_magico(int* poder_gandalf, int* poder_saruman){

    char ganador;

    if ( *poder_gandalf > *poder_saruman){
        ganador == 'C';
    }else if (*poder_gandalf < *poder_saruman){
        ganador =='S';
    }else if (*poder_saruman = *poder_gandalf){
        ganador == 'E';
    }

    return ganador;

}


int main() {

    int poder_1;
    int poder_2;
    char resultado;

    printf ("Ingrese el poder de Gandalf\n");
    scanf("%i", &poder_1);

    printf("Ingrese el poder de Sauron\n");
    scanf("%i", &poder_2);  

    if (poder_1 > poder_2) {
        poder_1 +=20;
        poder_2 -=10;
    } else if ( poder_1< poder_2){
        poder_2 +=20;
        poder_1 -=10;
    } else if (poder_1 = poder_2) {
        poder_2 +=5;
        poder_1 +=5;
    }

    resultado = duelo_magico(&poder_1, &poder_2);

    printf ("El ganador es: %c", resultado);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*tengo que usar en la función con pasaje por referencia que aún me es difícil entender*" Te es difícil de entender porque en [tag:c] no existe el concepto de referencia, menos aún pasar por referencia. **NO estás pasando nada por referencia**, pasas las direcciones de memoria de diferentes variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu fallo está en la función `duelo_magico()`

Estas intentando asignar a la variable ganador un valor de forma incorrecta.

**Cambia:**

```
ganador == 'C';
```

**Por**

```
ganador = 'C';
```

Otra cosa tambien, es tu `else if`:

```
} else if (poder_1 = poder_2) {
    poder_2 +=5;
    poder_1 +=5;
}
```

Con solo un signo `=` estas asignado valores, cuando lo que se pretende es comparar.

Quedaría así:

```
} else if (poder_1 == poder_2) {
    poder_2 +=5;
    poder_1 +=5;
}
```

Tu código completo con los cambios mencionados:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char duelo_magico(int* poder_gandalf, int* poder_saruman){

    char ganador;

    if ( *poder_gandalf > *poder_saruman){
        ganador = 'C';
    }else if (*poder_gandalf < *poder_saruman){
        ganador ='S';
    }else {
        ganador = 'E';
    }   
}


int main() {

    int poder_1;
    int poder_2;
    char resultado;

    printf ("Ingrese el poder de Gandalf\n");
    scanf("%i", &poder_1);

    printf("Ingrese el poder de Sauron\n");
    scanf("%i", &poder_2);  

    if (poder_1 > poder_2) {
        poder_1 += 20;
        poder_2 -= 10;
    } else if ( poder_1 < poder_2){
        poder_2 += 20;
        poder_1 -= 10;

    } else if (poder_1 == poder_2) {
        poder_2 += 5;
        poder_1 += 5;
    }


    resultado = duelo_magico(&poder_1, &poder_2);

    printf ("El ganador es: %c", resultado);

    return 0;
}
```